# Why am I getting a Fatal error when I try removing an element from array inside a loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, runtime-error

I have an array, I want to do some filtering in it, however, it gives me a runtime error. Is there any alternative way of doing this? (without using closures)

```
var arr = [4,5,6,7]

for i in 0..<arr.count - 1 {
    
    if arr[i] > 2 {
        arr.remove(at: i)
    }
}
print(arr)
```

Comment: Because you modifying `arr` inside the `for in` loop

Comment: Using `filter` is the best way to filter an array. Do you have a good reason for not wanting to use closures?...

Comment: Apart from the crash the last item is never going to be removed not even if the array is `[0,1,2,7]`

Comment: regarding the fatal error the easiest approach to avoid it is to iterate the collection indices in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [4, 5, 6, 7]
arr = arr.filter { $0 <= 2 }
print(arr)
```

Comment: The closure code to the filter should be `$0 <= 2`, not `$0 < 2` (as pointed out by @Shadowrun)

Comment: Array conforms to RangeReplaceableCollection. Since Swift 4 there is a mutating method called `removeAll(where:)` that you can pass a predicate exactly for this purpose. `arr.removeAll { $0 > 2 }`

Answer (score 1):

Think about what your code does.

```
    
    if arr[i] > 2 { //#2
        arr.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

1. At #1, it looks at the current number of elements in the array and sets the end value of the loop to 3. So the loop will run from 0 to 3.
2. At #2, each element in the array is greater than 2, so it gets removed from the array.

   1. At i == 0 the 4 is removed. Now there are 3 elements
   2. At i == 1, the
      5 is removed. Now there are 2 elements
   3. At i == 2, it attempts to
      fetch an element at index 2, and crashes with an index out of range
      error.

You are mutating the array as you attempt to iterate through it. Don't do that.

As others have said, use filter instead:

```
arr = arr.filter { $0 <= 2 }
```

If you really want to use a for loop and remove elements via index, loop through the array backwards:

```
var arr = [4,5,6,7]

for index in stride(from: arr.count-1, to: -1, by: -1) {
    let thisValue = arr[index]
    print("arr[\(index)]=\(thisValue)")
    if thisValue > 2 {
        arr.remove(at: index)
        print("->> removing \(thisValue) from arr at index \(index)")
    }
}

print("\nAfter for loop, arr contains \(arr.count) items")
arr.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

That ouputs:

```
arr[3]=7
->> removing 7 from arr at index 3
arr[2]=6
->> removing 6 from arr at index 2
arr[1]=5
->> removing 5 from arr at index 1
arr[0]=4
->> removing 4 from arr at index 0

After for loop, arr contains 0 items
```

Comment: Careful, the opposite of > 2, is not < 2, it's either ! $0 >2 or you can say <= 2

Comment: Good catch. My bad.

Comment: I just copied the filter code from another answer, not thinking about the fact that filter specifies the condition for keeping an element, and my reverse-order-looping code has logic to figure out what elements to **remove**. I forgot that the logic is inverted for the 2 cases, and missed the switch from ">" to "<" (which should have been "<=")

Comment: @DuncanC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672848/why-am-i-getting-a-fatal-error-when-i-try-removing-an-element-from-array-inside#comment117879168_66673797

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of why mutation is best avoided.
If you're manipulating an array and iterating over it at the same time, the index values are going to be invalid, because what was at index 4, will now be at index 3 if you delete something at position 1.
You can do it without 'using closures':

```
var idxToRemove: [Int] = []

for (idx, i) in arr.enumerated() {
    if i > 2 {
        idxToRemove.append(idx)
    }
}

for i in idxToRemove.reversed() {
    arr.remove(at: i)
}
```

But what you want is: `let arr = [4,5,6,7].filter { $0 <= 2 }`

Comment: Why do two passes, if you're just going to iterate it backwards on the second pass and remove the items to be removed? In order to avoid mutating while iterating? You have at least 2X the time complexity and probably 2X - 3X the memory footprint with this approach. It **does** avoid mutating while iterating though...

Comment: You could enumerate the array in reverse order, mutating as you go, but that’s maybe less easy to see what’s going on?

Comment: That's what I did in that part of my answer. (Like you, my suggestion is "just use filter".)

Comment: @Shadowrun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672848/why-am-i-getting-a-fatal-error-when-i-try-removing-an-element-from-array-inside#comment117879168_66673797